# SQL code in VBA showing unexpected symbol error

Tags: vba, postgresql, excel

If I run the below SQL in PGAdmin it works fine and converts the eventdate as required, but as soon as I try to add this to EXCEL VBA I get a unexpected symbol error (

Can someone tell me why this error is occurring?

```
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=oledb;"
Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

Dim DATA As String
DATA = "SELECT DISTINCT hist.master_id, hist.eventdate, to_date(case " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 8 then hist.eventdate " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 6 then concat(hist.eventdate,'01') " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 4 then concat(hist.eventdate,'0101') " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 0 then concat(hist.eventdate,'18000101') " _
    & "else '18000101' end,'YYYYMMDD') as eventdate2, hist.entity_ty, hist.read_code, hist.read_term, hist.priority, hist.enddate, " _
& "char_length(hist.enddate) enddate_length " _
& "FROM hist INNER JOIN person p ON hist.master_id=p.entity_id " _
& "WHERE char_length(hist.enddate) = 0 and to_date(case " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 8 then hist.eventdate " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 6 then concat(hist.eventdate,'01') " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 4 then concat(hist.eventdate,'0101') " _
    & "when char_length(hist.eventdate) = 0 then concat(hist.eventdate,'18000101') " _
    & "else '18000101' end,'YYYYMMDD') < '2014-01-01' " _
& "ORDER BY hist.master_id "

Set rs = conn.Execute(DATA)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that the problem is the date field.
When you build a SQL statement that contains date or time criteria, you must enclose the date or time with the number sign (#) delimiter.

Example:

```
costrSQL = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >#3-1-2009#;"
```

I suggest also to remove some parts of the query and try again, so you can identify the query part that contains the problem.

Comment: `#` delimiters are an peculiarity of Microsoft Access.